# Trying to get a loop to restart when using a shuffled array

Tags: python, for-loop, psychopy, nested-for-loop

Dear Stackoverflow fam,

I wish to run some experiments whereby I import some parameters for a stimulus (random dot kinematogram) and I chose to do this by creating a CSV with said parameters (total of 8 parameters I wish to cycle through). I need to pseudo-randomise the trials so I used the numpy.random.shuffle function to create this array. With this new array "shuffledRDK" i made the following loop

```
for b in range(2):
    for fps in range(120):
        blank_trial.draw()
        mywin.flip()
        time.sleep(6) 
        print("Trial: " +str(trial_counter) + " , Orientation " +str(shuffledRDK[x,0]) + " Coherence " +str(shuffledRDK[x,1]))
        trial_counter += 1
        if x in range (9):
            x += 1
            for fps in range(120):
                SignalDots = visual.DotStim(win=mywin, color=(1, 1, 1), dir=(shuffledRDK[x-1,0]), coherence=(shuffledRDK[x-1,1]), fieldSize=(20,20), speed=1, dotSize=5, dotLife=3, nDots=50, fieldShape='circle')
                SignalDots.draw()
                mywin.flip()
```

My issue is that at the end of the 8th parameter I wish for the cycle to start again. I get IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8 which I understand is out of the boundaries of the array but I don't know how to restart it. I've tried putting in if x > 8 statements or similar lines but I still get the index error. Would someone be able to help me out please?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can get useful help here at SO on general Python/numpy programming but there are so many PsychoPy-specific issues with this code that I’m not sure where to even start…  I would STRONGLY advise you to use the Builder to generate your experiment code, and restrict yourself to just adding any non-timing-critical code snippets needed, at least until you get much more familiar with the PsychoPy API. Regardless, you really should be using the dedicated support forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org to get much more knowledgeable guidance than you’ll find here.

Comment: Dear Michael, Thanks a lot for the pro tip. I will try the builder and utilise the psychopy forum! Many thanks again for taking the time to provide help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to increment x up each time; it will do it on it's own as it iterates through the loop. I suppose you are doing this because you want your x to start at 1 and end at 9? you can specify that range explicitly.

```
for b in range(2):
    for fps in range(120):
        blank_trial.draw()
        mywin.flip()
        time.sleep(6) 
        print("Trial: " +str(trial_counter) + " , Orientation " +str(shuffledRDK[x,0]) + " Coherence " +str(shuffledRDK[x,1]))
        trial_counter += 1
        if x in range (1, 9):
            for fps in range(120):
                SignalDots = visual.DotStim(win=mywin, color=(1, 1, 1), dir=(shuffledRDK[x-1,0]), coherence=(shuffledRDK[x-1,1]), fieldSize=(20,20), speed=1, dotSize=5, dotLife=3, nDots=50, fieldShape='circle')
                SignalDots.draw()
                mywin.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a variant using the `data.createFactorialTrialList()` permutation method and a `.yaml` configuration file
i edited the `for` loops to my understanding, as i cannot deduct what you are trying to do completely

```
from psychopy import core, visual, event, data
from psychopy.iohub.client import launchHubServer
import yaml

io = launchHubServer()
display = io.devices.display
mywin = visual.Window([640, 480], units='pix')


factors_info = yaml.load(open('stim_factors.yaml'))
stim_permutation = data.createFactorialTrialList(factors_info)
trial_handler = data.TrialHandler(trialList = stim_permutation, method ='random', nReps = 1)

for b in range(1):
    for fps in range(1):
        for stim in trial_handler:
            print(f'stim {trial_handler.thisN + 1:d}/{trial_handler.nTotal:d}')
            signal_dots = visual.DotStim(win=mywin, color=(1, 1, 1),
                                         dir        = trial_handler.thisTrial['dir'],
                                         coherence  = trial_handler.thisTrial['coher'],
                                         fieldSize  = trial_handler.thisTrial['field_size'],
                                         speed      = trial_handler.thisTrial['speed'],
                                         dotSize    = trial_handler.thisTrial['dot_size'],
                                         dotLife    = trial_handler.thisTrial['dot_life'],
                                         nDots      = trial_handler.thisTrial['n_dots'],
                                         fieldShape = 'circle')
            signal_dots.draw()
mywin.flip(); event.waitKeys()


io.quit(); mywin.close()
core.quit()
```

you can see the contents of the `.yaml` file on the picture's left
[image]